# can you set keyboard shortcut to toggle a System Preferences setting on mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, applescript, system-preferences

I very frequently have to go into System Preferences to toggle a trackpad setting or change the display color settings inside accessibility. I can't seem to find a way to be able to do these through keyboard shortcuts. For some of these settings, there are external apps that can accomplish the goal but for things like changing the accessibility zoom setting from split-screen to picture-in-picture seems to only be possible through sys preferences panel.

If there is a way access these with bash/applescripts or any type of scripting, that's even better since I know my way around them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur**  with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Zoom" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell pop up button 1 of group 1 of window 1
            if its value is "Split screen" then
                click
                delay 0.1
                click menu item "Picture-in-picture" of menu 1
            else if its value is "Picture-in-picture" then
                click
                delay 0.1
                click menu item "Split screen" of menu 1
            else
                click
                delay 0.1
                click menu item "Split screen" of menu 1
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be used in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* using a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the default *code* with it, and assigned a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

Note that assigning a *global keyboard shortcut* can be difficult to not step on a *keyboard shortcut* of whichever *application* has focus when the *global keyboard shortcut* is pressed and also may require adding that *application* to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**

It may be better to use any of the *third-party applications* that can handle triggering **AppleScript** *scripts* with a *keyboard shortcut* than to use an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*. I use [FastScripts](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) and I'm not associated with its developer, just a satisfied user of the product.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can also be use in an **AppleScript** *application* as well.

As coded, if the current *value* of the **Zoom style:** *pop-up menu* is set to either **Split screen** or **Picture-in-picture** it toggles between them. If it's set to **Full screen** it toggles it to **Split screen**.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses **UI Scripting** and as such some **UI elements** may briefly appear on screen, and in this particular use case as coded one will see the **Zoom style:** *pop-up menu* as it toggles between the choices.

If you would rather see the entire **UI** of **System Preferences** while it toggles the target *pop-up menu*, then:

**Change:**

```applescript
tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Zoom" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
```

**To:**

```applescript
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Zoom" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    activate
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Wow this works phenomenally, I wasn't aware you could automate button clicks through applescript. Thanks so much for all the very helpful details you provided!